# Can't put replica to ISR in Kafka 2.0

Tags: apache-kafka

On old Kafka 2.0.0.3.1.0.0-78 (HDP) we're facing an interesting issue with ISR. So, actually
we don't have ISR accordingly to replication factor for certain paritions. For instance:

```
Topic:yb_test3  PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:3
    Topic: yb_test3 Partition: 0    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1005,1008    Isr: 1002,1008,1005
    Topic: yb_test3 Partition: 1    Leader: 1005    Replicas: 1005  Isr: 1005
    Topic: yb_test3 Partition: 2    Leader: 1010    Replicas: 1010,1005,1008    Isr: 1010,1005,1008
```

We've tried to play with partition reassignment as well as preferred replica election but without success.

The most interesting behaviour observed during troubleshooting (and playing with partition
reassignment) was the following. The attempt was to make partition 1 (on broker 1002) in ISR list.
So, initially we have:

```
Topic:yb_test3  PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:3
    Topic: yb_test3 Partition: 0    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1005,1008    Isr: 1002,1008,1005
    Topic: yb_test3 Partition: 1    Leader: 1005    Replicas: 1005  Isr: 1005
    Topic: yb_test3 Partition: 2    Leader: 1010    Replicas: 1010,1005,1008    Isr: 1010,1005,1008
```

And in Zookeeper:

```
[zk: prod-nn-0006.pv.mts.ru:2181(CONNECTED) 0] get /brokers/topics/yb_test3/partitions/1/state
{"controller_epoch":163,"leader":1005,"version":1,"leader_epoch":90,"isr":[1005]}
cZxid = 0x1a054a0c57
ctime = Thu Feb 16 11:06:41 MSK 2023
mZxid = 0x1a0d0b6c0e
mtime = Thu Mar 28 13:24:09 MSK 2024
pZxid = 0x1a054a0c57
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 262
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 81
numChildren = 0
```

We see leader_epoch = 90. Now let's do reassign partitions to (1005,1002,1008) via triggering kafka-reassign-partitions.sh
tool. As a result:

```
Topic:yb_test3  PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:3
    Topic: yb_test3 Partition: 0    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1005,1008    Isr: 1002,1008,1005
    Topic: yb_test3 Partition: 1    Leader: 1005    Replicas: 1005,1002,1008    Isr: 1005
    Topic: yb_test3 Partition: 2    Leader: 1010    Replicas: 1010,1005,1008    Isr: 1010,1005,1008
```

So, 1002 and 1008 are not in ISR.

Checking trace logs reveals the following procedure. In /var/log/kafka/state-change.log on 1002 (where broker and conrollers are currently)
we see:

```
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,783] TRACE [Controller id=1002 epoch=163] Sending become-leader LeaderAndIsr request PartitionState(controllerEpoch=163, leader=1005, leaderEpoch=91, isr=1005, zkVersion=263, replicas=1005,1002,1008, isNew=false) to broker 1005 for partition yb_test3-1 (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,783] TRACE [Controller id=1002 epoch=163] Sending become-follower LeaderAndIsr request PartitionState(controllerEpoch=163, leader=1005, leaderEpoch=91, isr=1005, zkVersion=263, replicas=1005,1002,1008, isNew=false) to broker 1008 for partition yb_test3-1 (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,783] TRACE [Controller id=1002 epoch=163] Sending become-follower LeaderAndIsr request PartitionState(controllerEpoch=163, leader=1005, leaderEpoch=91, isr=1005, zkVersion=263, replicas=1005,1002,1008, isNew=false) to broker 1002 for partition yb_test3-1 (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,783] TRACE [Controller id=1002 epoch=163] Sending UpdateMetadata request PartitionState(controllerEpoch=163, leader=1005, leaderEpoch=90, isr=[1005], zkVersion=262, replicas=[1005, 1002, 1008], offlineReplicas=[]) to brokers Set(1002, 1008, 1005, 1010) for partition yb_test3-1 (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,783] TRACE [Controller id=1002 epoch=163] Sent LeaderAndIsr request (Leader:1005,ISR:1005,LeaderEpoch:91,ControllerEpoch:163) with new assigned replica list 1005,1002,1008 to leader 1005 for partition being reassigned yb_test3-1 (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,783] TRACE [Controller id=1002 epoch=163] Changed state of replica 1002 for partition yb_test3-1 from NonExistentReplica to NewReplica (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,783] TRACE [Controller id=1002 epoch=163] Sending become-follower LeaderAndIsr request PartitionState(controllerEpoch=163, leader=1005, leaderEpoch=90, isr=1005, zkVersion=262, replicas=1005,1002,1008, isNew=true) to broker 1002 for partition yb_test3-1 (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,783] TRACE [Controller id=1002 epoch=163] Sending UpdateMetadata request PartitionState(controllerEpoch=163, leader=1005, leaderEpoch=90, isr=[1005], zkVersion=262, replicas=[1005, 1002, 1008], offlineReplicas=[]) to brokers Set(1002, 1008, 1005, 1010) for partition yb_test3-1 (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,783] TRACE [Controller id=1002 epoch=163] Changed state of replica 1008 for partition yb_test3-1 from NonExistentReplica to NewReplica (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,783] TRACE [Controller id=1002 epoch=163] Sending become-follower LeaderAndIsr request PartitionState(controllerEpoch=163, leader=1005, leaderEpoch=90, isr=1005, zkVersion=262, replicas=1005,1002,1008, isNew=true) to broker 1008 for partition yb_test3-1 (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,783] TRACE [Controller id=1002 epoch=163] Sending UpdateMetadata request PartitionState(controllerEpoch=163, leader=1005, leaderEpoch=90, isr=[1005], zkVersion=262, replicas=[1005, 1002, 1008], offlineReplicas=[]) to brokers Set(1002, 1008, 1005, 1010) for partition yb_test3-1 (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,783] TRACE [Broker id=1002] Received LeaderAndIsr request PartitionState(controllerEpoch=163, leader=1005, leaderEpoch=91, isr=1005, zkVersion=263, replicas=1005,1002,1008, isNew=false) correlation id 2184 from controller 1002 epoch 163 for partition yb_test3-1 (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,784] TRACE [Broker id=1002] Handling LeaderAndIsr request correlationId 2184 from controller 1002 epoch 163 starting the become-follower transition for partition yb_test3-1 with leader 1005 (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,790] TRACE [Broker id=1002] Stopped fetchers as part of become-follower request from controller 1002 epoch 163 with correlation id 2184 for partition yb_test3-1 with leader 1005 (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,790] TRACE [Broker id=1002] Truncated logs and checkpointed recovery boundaries for partition yb_test3-1 as part of become-follower request with correlation id 2184 from controller 1002 epoch 163 with leader 1005 (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,792] TRACE [Broker id=1002] Started fetcher to new leader as part of become-follower request from controller 1002 epoch 163 with correlation id 2184 for partition yb_test3-1 with leader 1005 (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,792] TRACE [Broker id=1002] Completed LeaderAndIsr request correlationId 2184 from controller 1002 epoch 163 for the become-follower transition for partition yb_test3-1 with leader 1005 (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,792] TRACE [Broker id=1002] Cached leader info PartitionState(controllerEpoch=163, leader=1005, leaderEpoch=90, isr=[1005], zkVersion=262, replicas=[1005, 1002, 1008], offlineReplicas=[]) for partition yb_test3-1 in response to UpdateMetadata request sent by controller 1002 epoch 163 with correlation id 2185 (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,792] TRACE [Broker id=1002] Received LeaderAndIsr request PartitionState(controllerEpoch=163, leader=1005, leaderEpoch=90, isr=1005, zkVersion=262, replicas=1005,1002,1008, isNew=true) correlation id 2186 from controller 1002 epoch 163 for partition yb_test3-1 (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,792] WARN [Broker id=1002] Ignoring LeaderAndIsr request from controller 1002 with correlation id 2186 epoch 163 for partition yb_test3-1 since its associated leader epoch 90 is not higher than the current leader epoch 91 (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,801] TRACE [Broker id=1002] Cached leader info PartitionState(controllerEpoch=163, leader=1005, leaderEpoch=90, isr=[1005], zkVersion=262, replicas=[1005, 1002, 1008], offlineReplicas=[]) for partition yb_test3-1 in response to UpdateMetadata request sent by controller 1002 epoch 163 with correlation id 2187 (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,802] TRACE [Broker id=1002] Cached leader info PartitionState(controllerEpoch=163, leader=1005, leaderEpoch=90, isr=[1005], zkVersion=262, replicas=[1005, 1002, 1008], offlineReplicas=[]) for partition yb_test3-1 in response to UpdateMetadata request sent by controller 1002 epoch 163 with correlation id 2188 (state.change.logger)
```

So, what is interesting here and what we actually can't understand - the WARN message that LeaderAndIsr was ignored because its associated leader epoch 90 is not higher than the current leader epoch 91.

Indeed, leader_epoch was incremented (and in Zookeeper it is 91 now). But why controller sent twice:
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,783] TRACE [Controller id=1002 epoch=163] Sending become-follower LeaderAndIsr request PartitionState(controllerEpoch=163, leader=1005, leaderEpoch=91, isr=1005, zkVersion=263, replicas=1005,1002,1008, isNew=false) to broker 1002 for partition yb_test3-1 (state.change.logger)
[2024-03-28 13:28:10,783] TRACE [Controller id=1002 epoch=163] Sending become-follower LeaderAndIsr request PartitionState(controllerEpoch=163, leader=1005, leaderEpoch=90, isr=1005, zkVersion=262, replicas=1005,1002,1008, isNew=true) to broker 1002 for partition yb_test3-1 (state.change.logger)

And more specifically, why on the 2nd request the old leader_epoch was sent?

And the main question: how to deal with such a problem and make ISR correct? We tried to trigger controller change via Zookeeper but without any success. We have only one idea - use unclean.leader.election.enable=true and reboot broker 1005 (and probably 1002 will be used in such scenario) - but honestly we want to understand the root cause.

We tried partition reassignment, preferred replica election, switching to different controllers.